# Python bard api isn't working properly how to fix it?

Tags: python

I'm trying to use bard api to answer questions.

Here is my code:

```
import requests
from bardapi.constants import SESSION_HEADERS
from bardapi import Bard

token = "my token"

session = requests.Session()
session.headers = SESSION_HEADERS
session.cookies.set("__Secure-1PSID", token)
bard = Bard(token=token, session=session)

bard.get_answer('What is 1+1')['content']
```

Error:

```
Exception: SNlM0e value not found. Double-check __Secure-1PSID value or pass it as token='xxxxx'.
```

Im 100% sure that the token is correct.

Answer (score 2):

There is an ongoing issue about this behaviour which can be found [here](https://github.com/dsdanielpark/Bard-API/issues/99).

I can identify two potential solutions from this discussion:

First potential solution:

> Clear cookies of bard.google.com and try again
>
> - login into the account
> - F12 > Applications > Cookies > bard >    __Secure-1PSID
> - Copy cookie and paste into your code.

Second potential solution:

> Add additonal __Secure-1PSIDTS and __Secure-1PSIDCC cookies with
> "<VALUE>" as content
>
> ```py
> import requests from bardapi.constants
> import SESSION_HEADERS from bardapi
> import Bard
>
> token = "xxxxx"
>
> session = requests.Session()
> session.headers = SESSION_HEADERS
> session.cookies.set("__Secure-1PSID", token)
> session.cookies.set("__Secure-1PSIDTS", "<VALUE>")
> session.cookies.set("__Secure-1PSIDCC", "<VALUE>")
>
> bard = Bard(token=token, session=session)
> ```

Comment: the "__Secure-1PSIDTS" value is keep getting changed after 10mins, how can i capture the latest one before sending request?

Comment: @Debankan There's a [discussion regarding this topic](https://github.com/PawanOsman/GoogleBard/issues/29) as well. Maybe you are able to interpret the rather cryptic "the response has Set-Cookie" message and find a programmatic solution.

Comment: Is it still possible with Bard being changed to Gemini ?

Answer (score 0):

how is it going, I think you can use this code, I checked this way today 30 November and this is still working.

```
import requests
from bardapi import SESSION_HEADERS
from bardapi import Bard

token = "xxxxx"

session = requests.Session()
session.headers = SESSION_HEADERS
session.cookies.set("__Secure-1PSID", token)
session.cookies.set("__Secure-1PSIDTS","xxxxx")
session.cookies.set("__Secure-1PSIDCC","xxxxx")

bard = Bard(token=token, session=session)

print(bard.get_answer("Hi")['content'])
```